# Syntax error for time_t st_mtime line?

Tags: c

Why does this program produce a syntax error when built in Ubuntu?

```
#include "stdio.h"  
#include "stdlib.h"     
#include "string.h"    
#include "time.h"  
#include "sys/types.h"  
#include "sys/stat.h"

int main()
{
    time_t st_mtime;  
    printf("Hello\n");  
    return 0;  
}
```

Here's what I get when I try to build this:

```
$ gcc -o test1 test1.c  
test1.c: In function ?main?:
test1.c:10: error: expected ?=?, ?,?, ?;?, ?asm? or ?__attribute__? before ?.? token  
test1.c:10: error: expected expression before ?.? token
```

Inspecting the preprocessor output:

```
$  gcc -E test1.c > test1.d
```

Shows line 10 as:

```
time_t st_mtim.tv_sec;
```

The error occurs only if I include both "sys/stat.h" & "time.h" files.

Comment: `"` is only for local files. These should be `#include<stdio.h>`, and so forth.

Comment: st_mtime is probably a preprocessor macro like `#define st_mtime time_array[xxxx]`. And the name is prefixed with 'st_' for a reason...

Answer (score 5):

If you `grep` `/usr/include` for `st_mtime`, you'll find the following:

```
$ grep -r st_mtime /usr/include | grep define
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stat.h:# define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec
```

So the problem stems from your use of the variable name `st_mtime`.

Comment: This makes it a non useable for general purpose. It is acting as a 'C' reserved word. Are there more of this kind?

Comment: @user1054965: Lots, in header files. I don't think you can know them all, but if you ever have a weird problem like this, it doesn't hurt to try changing the variable name as a debugging step. :)

Comment: POSIX documents the reserved words for various headers. For `stat.h`, `st_*` is in the reserved namespace, so you can't use it yourself.